# cygnus version installation with hadoop 2.6

Tags: fiware-cygnus

hello i would like to install cygnus from sources 
http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html
and i have an already hadoop apache 2.6/0  installed.

The cygnus pom.xml  show that version is    0.11.0

```
<groupId>com.telefonica.iot</groupId>
<artifactId>cygnus</artifactId>
<version>0.11.0_SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Question: is it compatible with hadoop 2.6.0

Best regards

phil

Comment: Specifically, never tried with Hadoop 2.6.0. Why not simply testing it? :) If some problem arises, then we can work on fixing it.